# Get array number from Array with String value

Tags: php, arrays, string, integer

I have an array with string value in PHP for example : `arr['apple'], arr['banana']`, and many more -about 20-30 data (get it from some process). Now I want to get its value and return it to one variable.

For example, I have Original array is like this:

```
$arr['Apple']
$arr['Banana']
and more..
```

and result that I want is like this:

```
$arr[0] = "Apple"
$arr[1] = "Banana"
and more..
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using array_keys()?

```
$new_array = array_keys($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_flip()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

```
$new_arr = array_flip($old_arr);
```

[Demonstration](https://eval.in/142461)

Comment: definitely, the simplest way around :)

Comment: This way, all the extra values in the array would be removed (since array keys must be unique).

Comment: @AmalMurali, Let's worry about that later... I hope he said more... Maybe it is Pineapple , Guava , Papaya.. yeah a lot more fruits are there right ? ;)

Comment: @CrossVander: The result will be an array. You can't echo/print it. Use `print_r($new_arr);` to inspect the contents of the array. Or use `implode()` if you want to join them into a comma-separated string: `echo implode(', ', $new_arr);`.

Comment: Hello, I want to ask what is "=>1" for? because my code is now like this:
https://eval.in/142463
And I still can't call the variable $new[0], its output is: "Undefined offset: 0 in"

Comment: Because `$tempword` is not defined. What does it contain ? Also it is very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Helo SHankar, sorry for an uncleared problem. What I want to create is a plagiarism program, in my code there's a long code that have get the result for the $tempword. Check this out : https://eval.in/142466

Comment: Hello Shankar, already find it, using array_keys.. like Jason OOO answer... thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

use foreach loop

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $new_var[] = $key; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array_keys` function:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
```

It returns an array of all the keys in array.